# laravel get session data and order by latest

Tags: laravel, session

I'm working on a session data with Laravel and I can store sessions into a variable and retrieving the whole data. But my problem is I want to order the session to the latest 5 id's from the session stored.

Storing session

```
session()->push('products.recently_viewed', $product->getKey());
```

Retrieving session

```
$ids = session()->get('products.recently_viewed');
$recently_viewed = Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

The retrieving is working fine, I only want to get the latest 5 id's from the session `products.recently_viewed`

e.g.

data from sessions

```
[1,3,7,6,8,9,11,2]
```

data I want to get

```
[2,11,9,8,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need array_slice and array_reverse

```
$items = array_reverse(array_slice($yourSessionArray, -5));
```

-5 means "start at five elements before the end of the array".
the reverse will reverse the order of the array so the last is first.

Comment: thanks @Cameron, I want a unique to filter duplicate id's also, should I do this?
`$items = array_reverse(array_slice(array_unique($recently_viewed_ids), -5));`